# Source Model Name when copy object

Tags: initialization, powerdesigner

How to get, when copying one object from model to model, the name of the Source model?
I Need it in table EventHandler initialize.

Thank you
David

Comment: What do you mean "copy one object"? Are you copying the object by script, doing a copy-paste, a model generation...? My idea would be to put the source model name in some extended attribute of the target model, to be reused during the copy operations...

Comment: I have two physical models. A and B.
In the A model is a table. Using by CTR+C from model A I can copy to model B (CTRL+ V)...
In both model is a extension with name "Autocolumn"...
THere is in extension -> Table - Eventhandler - initialize....
I Need there catch the source model name (A)....I need it for testing stereotyps and for other metods.


In model B the extension/event handler (initialize) catch copiing table, but do not know the source model....
Im afraid of, the next extended attribut in both models dont help me, because of know source model :-) - mayby I'm mistake